# Best strategy for gigantic SQL Server bulk Insert - high-frequency or low-frequency

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bulk-load

Is it better to bulk load N batches of 1 MB data (high freq) or 1 batch of X MB data (low freq)?

The problem for me is that parsing and processing the data also takes time, so it seems that parsing, processing and persisting a gigantic dataset in parallel is not the best approach because it results in high-frequency bulk inserts.

Rather, parsing & processing should accumulate into a large batch of X size and then dispatch a (parallelised) bulk insert of that batch?

Is this correct? If so, what is a recommended size of X ?

Comment: without concrete data and use-case the question does not have much of a meaning. Only with concrete data (and platform specs) can metrics be made and decide concretely

Comment: High frequency for big batch is probably always the best decision. Huge operation may lead to a huge error that bury everything. Also, more time is needed for operation, more possibilities there are for network or I/O error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal size of the batch depends on your hardware, what processing you are doing, the amount of existing data. Only you can tell.

A smart algorithm would try to insert few batches of size `N` and measure the performance, then few batches of size `2*N`, then few batches of size `4*N`, etc. until the performance starts to degrade and automatically settle on the optimal batch size.

As the database grows the optimal size of the batch would change as well, so the algorithm should adjust itself with time.

If it is a one-off task, do few tests with various batch sizes manually.